# combobox setting blank value while round trip to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, mvvm

i'm having a xaml view which consist of several comboboxes.below is one of my combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboPT"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Height="25"
                      Width="170"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding Path="PT"
                             Mode="TwoWay" />
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedPT"
                             Mode="TwoWay" />
                </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

its showing the value binded to it when i first visit the page but getting blank when i perform any action that causes a server side round trip on the form.

Below is my code that i used to bind data to combobox

```
public Dictionary<string, string> PT
    {
        get { return _PT; }
        set
        {
            _PT = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("PT");
            if (_PT.Count > 0 && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPT.Value) || ResetPT))
            {
                ResetPT = false;
                SelectedPT = _PT.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPT");
            }
        }
    }
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedPT
    {
        get { return _SelectedPT; }
        set
        {
            bool bIsNull = _SelectedPT.Equals(null);
            if (bIsNull || !_SelectedPT.Equals(value))
            {
                _SelectedPT = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPT");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any other code you can share? What you've listed here isn't very helpful for the problem.

Comment: @dgarbacz: added the code that i used to bind the combobox

Comment: I would put breakpoints on your `set` conditions. Just looked at those they don't really make sense to me. What is `_PT.FirstOrDefault()` supposed to be returning? I feel like that always returns `null`

Comment: i checked it with debugging.PT always returning `NON-NULL` value

Comment: When you make a second request, is the `OnPropertyChanged` of PT firing off again due to a data-rebind or something?

Comment: yup.that was the thing.